# I need to insert data for 100 rows; it has unique key constraints as datatypes number and string. How do I do it?

Tags: sql, postgresql, dbeaver

```sql
INSERT INTO TABLENAME (id, country, reference, status ) Values (21, 'INDIA', '0001', 'Pass' )
```

here id and reference are unique.

how do insert 1000 records of any loop concept in postgresql DB tool DBeaver, Please help.

I am trying manually to insert the record individually which takes a lot of time. So please help me with it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `reference` is incremental as well, below will work. You can tune the loop

```
DO
$do$
BEGIN 
   FOR i IN 1..1000 LOOP
      INSERT INTO TABLENAME (id, country, reference, status) 
      VALUES (i, 'INDIA',  LPAD(i::varchar, 4, '0'), 'Pass');
   END LOOP;
END
$do$;
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for a loop, generate_series() can do this for you:

```
INSERT INTO TABLENAME (id, country, reference, status )
SELECT i
     ,'INDIA'
     , to_char(i, '0000')
     , 'Pass'
FROM generate_series(1,1000) g(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Better not to go with the loop. An alternative way is to **import as CSV** via **[COPY](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/import-csv-file-into-posgresql-table/)** command.

This comes with its own pros & cons.